# Pass data from Row into Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a button in a webgrid row defined as such:

```
grid.Column("Fault", header: "Fault", format: (item) =>
            {
                if (item.Fault != null)
                {
                    return new HtmlString(string.Format("<input type='submit' id='btnShowFault' onclick='ShowFaultMessage({0})' value='Fault' />", item.Fault.Message));
                }

                return "";
            }))
```

This is my ShowFaultMessage function:

```
 function ShowFaultMessage(message) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Message/',       
        data: message,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            var w = window.open("/Home/Message", "Fault Message", "width=400, height=400");
            $(w.document.body).html(result.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

This is not working though. I know that item.Fault is correct because my If Block works in the column definition. But when I click the button, it throws an undefined reference exception. How can I make this work. I am new to MVC, but something like this is really easy with xaml. I refuse to believe it's not possible in razor/mvc.

EDIT: This is my action method for loading the popup window view:

```
 public ActionResult Message(string faultMessage)
    {
        var model = new MessageViewModel { Message = faultMessage };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Also edited my other code blocks to show their current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the return to be something like this

```
return new HtmlString(string.format("<input type='submit' id='btnShowFault' onclick='ShowFaultMessage({0})' value='Fault' />", item.Fault));
```

You need to use the string.format to insert the value into the string

Comment: So Fault is an object. Message is the string property I need from it. So I did what you showed but did item.Fault.Message in the string.format. I am now getting an error: Uncaught reference error: "My Fault Message" is not defined. So the item.Fault.Message is clearly being passed, but it has a problem with it.

Comment: That has to be the javascript. I would say it's throwing it on the JSON.stringify call. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but JSON.stringify expects an object that is then turned into a json string.

Comment: It's a js error. I got rid of the JSON call and it still shows that error. I'm just trying to pass that Message string into the Message action method in the Home controller so I can build up the model for that Popup that I want to show. I really thought this would be easy, but it appears to not be.

Comment: I edited my original post with your changes and my action method.

Comment: Is the Message Action being called or is the javascript failing before the call is made? In addition, why even make a call back to the server for this? Why not just pop a window from the javascript with the message?

Comment: It's breaking before calling the action. The Message View has some things in it. Like a formatted textbox and a button that copies the text to the clipboard if they want it. So the Message view has some things in it. It might also need to be expanded in the future with more buttons and what not. It's not just a simple popup text window.

Comment: That makes more sense. Can you step through the javascript and see exactly which line is causing it to break?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance as mvc is new to me. How do you step through it? Can I just put a break point in VS? If I expand the error that I see in the console tab in chrome debug, I see this: onclick @ About:1
About is my main page. The code in my post above is in a partial view that is rendered on the About page.

Comment: My suggestion for debugging it is to open the debugger that comes with your browser and step through it in that. Javascript is client side and I don't have any experience debugging it with visual studio. I use firefox and firebug which is a very useful debugging tool

Comment: So i think there is something wrong with the script reference. Googling my error shows that this error usually comes from not declaring the jquery library. So let me ask this. The code in my original post is in a partial view. Can you have javascript in a partial class?

Comment: Yes you can. You just need to make sure that in either the partial view or the view that calls the partial view that jQuery is included.

Comment: I have this both in my main view and the partial view:  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>.  I really am perplexed at why something that is simple is such a hassle in mvc...

Comment: To be clear the issue isn't MVC. I just tried that URL provided and I get a 404

Comment: I got it working. For some reason the comment section didn't render that URL correctly.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear it